# is "nor" applied into "were" and "was" in this sentence? "Nor were these practices confined to the decadent phases, was utterly subservient to style."

Tags: parallelism

now I'm confusing about nor with "were" and "was" in parallel structure in sentence.

full sentence is that

> **Nor** **were** these practices confined, as some scholars insist, to the later and supposedly decadent phases of the art Material, then, **was** utterly subservient to style.

I understood first meaning in parallel structure which is

> Nor were these practices confined to the the later and supposedly decadent phases of the art Materials

but I confused second content.
which is right between two meaning?

> Nor was this practice utterly subservient to style (using 'nor' with 'was')
>
> this practice was utterly subservient to style (not using 'nor' with 'was')

and second questions is why they use "was" instead of "were" at second parallel structure even though subject is "these practices"?

Comment: It looks to me like there's a period missing before *Materials*. This is the sort of error that arises frequently in exam-prep texts copied frequently from site to site.

Comment: Yep, period missing after "art".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's based on an improper transcription.

Answer (score 1):

I found some passage that tell that

"Nor were these practices confined, as some scholars insist, to the later and supposedly decadent phases of the art. Material, then, was utterly subservient to style."

there is "." after art. maybe, this is error of book. so, I closed this question.